# Recommendation for multiple ajax countdown timers (call per second)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm creating a system that has 100 count down timers.  Each timer makes an ajax call every second to get the endTime in the database and update the countdown time.  I need to call this every second because the endTime can change.  The system is currently working but its incredibly slow, and I'm curious if there is a better way than to call 100 ajax calls every second.

```
var countDownDate;
    var is_locked;
    var interval = 1000;

    function update_timer() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url('/Timer/getTimer');?>',
        data: {
          id: <?php echo $lane->id; ?>,
        },
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
          var image_url = null;
          $.each(response, function(k, v) {
            if (k == 'end_time') {
              countDownDate = new Date(v).getTime();
            }
            if (k == 'is_locked') {
              is_locked = v;
              if (is_locked == 1) {
                $('.myButton').prop('disabled', true);
              } else {
                $('.myButton').prop('disabled', false);
              }
            }
          })
          // Get today's date and time
          var now = new Date().getTime();

          // Find the distance between now and the count down date
          var distance = countDownDate - now;
          // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
          var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
          var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
          var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

          // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

          // If the count down is finished, write some text
          if (distance < 0) {
            //clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
          }
        },
        complete: function (data) {
          // Schedule the next
          setTimeout(update_timer, interval);
        }
      });
    }
    update_timer;
    setTimeout(update_timer, interval);
```

Comment: Websockets, maybe?

Comment: Are the 100 countdown timers work on the same HTML page ?

Comment: Or 1 ajax call for all the timers' data?

Comment: @ThumChoonTat yep, that was my plan, I'm in the middle of writing an answer using this approach now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Websockets is the clean and beautiful solution for this situation as commented by @CertainPerformance

How about this workaround as suggested by @Thum Choon Tat

> instead of let every one of the 100 timers make a request every 1
>   second to get his own `endTime` (100 requests a second), make only 1 request every second and
>   get **all** the `endtimes` of all the timers.

This is my plan

- We will use localStorage to share the data between all the tabs. and save these items in it:

  1. `lastRequeted` The the last time any HTML page made the request.
  2. `requesterId` the Id of the page that is responsible for firing the Ajax requests
  3. `timerId1` , `timerId2` , `timerId3` , .... will hold the `endTimes` for every timer
- Any page having one or more timer from the 100 timers can request the `endTimes` of all the timers, and set the `lastRequeted` value to now, and set `requesterId` to it's Id
- We run an interval on the client side every second to check `lastRequeted` , if it is too old " like 4 seconds ago" , it will do the request, if it's new then it get's the data it needs from `timerIdX` items.
- only one HTML page will register it self as the `requesterId` no other HTMl page will do requests unless the data is too old

This is the JS code you will use on any HTML that has a timer

```
var requesterId = Math.random(); // random Id for this page

setInterval(function (){
    var ts = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    var lastRequested = localStorage.getItem('lastRequested');
    var currentRequester = localStorage.getItem('requesterId');

    if (requesterId == currentRequester ||  (ts - lastRequested > 4)){
        // if I'm the current requester or the last requested time is older than 4 seconds, I will do the request
        localStorage.settItem('requesterId', requesterId);
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Timer/getAllTimers',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
             localStorage.setItem('lastRequested', Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));
             for (var i =0; i < data.length; i++){
                 var timerId = data[i].timerId;
                 var timerEndTime = data[i].timerEndTime;
                 localStorage.setItem(timerId, timerEndTime);
             }
             updateTimersEndTimes();
        }
    } else {
        // the data is updated I will get the timer endTime
        updateTimersEndTimes();

    }
}, 1000);

/**
 * update timers endTimes from the localStorage
*/
function updateTimersEndTimes()
{
     /*
      // pseudo code
      $("Div#timersOnPage .timer").each(function(){
          var timerId = $(this).data("timerId");
          var timerEndtime = LocalStorage.getItem(timerId);
          $(this).data('timerEndTime', timerEndtime);
     });

     */
}
```

On the server you will send the endTime for all the timers

/Timer/getAllTimers

```
<?php
//buid the array from your database
$timersArray = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
    $timer = new stdClass();
    $timer->timerId = $i;
    $timer->timerEndTime = "2019-08-23 05:02:23";//changes for every timer
    $timersArray[] = $timer;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($timersArray);
exit;
```

Now every HTML that has a timer will not fire a request, however it will check every second if the timers data is updated, then it will use it.